# Display category results as list in WordPress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site that displays information for each organization member  in a post. Each member/post has assigned categories so visitors can filter members by categories. For each listing/post, it displays the categories that are checked for that member in the post. Until recently, it displayed the categories as a bulleted list. For some reason now, even though the code in the page template has not changed, all the categories are displayed in one long line, running together. (My guess is this happened when the version of WordPress automatically updated.) I believe this should be an easy fix but I just don't have the knowledge so I'm hoping someone here can help me.

In the original file, it’s just really simple code:

```
<p><b>This farm/business falls under the following categories:</b></p>
<?php the_category  (  $separator, $parents, $post_id ); ?>
```

When I view how it used to be via web.archive.org, it shows that there was code infused somehow with ul and li formatting resulting in:

```
<p><b>This farm/business falls under the following categories:</b></p>
<ul class="post-categories">
  <li>[each category]
</ul>
```

Is there code I can add here to force the list formatting again? Thanks!

Comment: `the_category( $separator, $parents, $post_id );` return a list in html, so it should echo the categories in a list, what does your html look like now?

Comment: When I inspect the html on the live page, there is no list formatting. It is displays the results in a paragraph with no line breaks or any other formatting. All categories are displayed in a single line.

Comment: what's the value of `$separator`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that question. I'm working in the single.php file and there doesn't seem to be any other code in the file that pertains to this function.

Comment: Add `var_dump($seperator);`

Comment: Add that where? And what will that accomplish?

Comment: At the end of single.php

Comment: I'm not super knowledgeable about php but assume you can't just add that so I tried it as <?php var_dump($seperator);?> and <?var_dump($seperator);?>. Neither seemed to make any difference on the page.